# ImportError: No module named firebase_admin, while trying to commit data to firestore in dataflow

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, importerror

I am currently trying to commit data to firestore from my python apache beam dataflow pipeline.

But I am consistenly getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 609, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 167, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 49, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 50, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 65, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    with self.shuffle_source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 69, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 159, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 85, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 233, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
    self.output(wvalue.with_value((k, wvalue.value)))
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 159, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 85, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 392, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 393, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 488, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 496, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 521, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 494, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 395, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process
    self._invoke_per_window(
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 432, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_per_window
    output_processor.process_outputs(
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 561, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
    def process_outputs(self, windowed_input_element, results):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 592, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 85, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 392, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    with self.scoped_process_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 393, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 488, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 496, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 537, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    six.raise_from(new_exn, original_traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 718, in raise_from
    raise value
ImportError: No module named firebase_admin [while running 'Batches to Firestore']
```

I am currently calling firebase_admin whilst inside my function, although this hasn't made a difference compared to calling it at the start of the file.

```
class FireBatch(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        """
        Make a batch element and send to firestore
        """
        import firebase_admin
        from firebase_admin import credentials
        from firebase_admin import firestore

        cred = credentials.Certificate('./creds/pipeCreds.json')
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

        db = firestore.Client()
```

Is there a way I can get dataflow to recognise firebase_admin within the pipeline? Or commit the data from the pipeline to firestore?

I have installed all the necessary packages, upgraded pip, refreshed the credentials, tried google.cloud.firestore instead of fire_base admin.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was from not initializing with the Google SDK, I was trying to initialize with GitBash and obviously the configuration wasn't set upt properly.

The next step was to initialize the app with a requirements.txt file.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

After that, only include the files needed for the app within the requirements.txt file, and initialize the app by adding:

```
--requirements_file requirements.txt
```

Also, it was necessary to change from `firebase_admin==2.11.0` to `firebase_admin==2.8.0` as this was bringing up an error.